# SQL select a date range for each parent/child family of items

Tags: sql, join, parent-child

I have a hierarchy (temp table) built for all parent/child type items with range keys. I have a table (LastOrdr) that has the last order date for all items (regardless parent/child). Then I have the master item table with all items.

I have a query that selects all non parent/child items that meet a certain lastorderdate criteria. It's a simple query that joins master item table with the LastOrdr table to get the max(lastorderdate) from a supplied user parameter.

My challenge is to do the same for the parent/child products. For parent/child items (one parent and could have up to 8 child but 2/3 in most cases). The selection is, for a family, the max(lastorderdate) has to be applied to the whole family. What I mean is, if I have 3 child for a parent, I need to find the max of all 4 (1 parent and 3 child) items in this family from LastOrdr.lastorderdate, then compare it to the user supplied parameter. if it meets the criteria as a family, I want to select that family, otherwise, discard it.

Some guidance to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Table1 (master item):

```
itemID    ParentID    Descrip    ......
21         2           .....
22         2           .....
23         2           .....
24         2           .....
27         3           .....
29         3           .....
33         3           .....
41         3           .....
......................
```

Table2 (LastOrdr):

```
ItemID    lastorderdate
2          2014-01-01
21         2014-07-21
21         2015-01-12
22         2013-01-01
23         2014-04-01
27         2013-01-23
...........................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query returns what you want.

```
declare @master table (itemID int, ParentID int)
insert @master values
(21         ,2 ),
( 22         ,2), 
( 23         ,2 ),
( 24         ,2 ),
( 27         ,3 ),
( 29         ,3 ),
( 33         ,3 ),
( 41         ,3),
(2, 2), --I added this data
(3, 2)  --
--,(44,21) --if you wish grandchild

declare @LastOrdr table(ItemID int, lastorderdate date)
insert @LastOrdr values
(2          ,'2014-01-01'),
(21         ,'2014-07-21'),
(21         ,'2015-01-12'),
(22         ,'2013-01-01'),
(23         ,'2014-04-01'),
(27         ,'2013-01-23')
--,(44, '2015-04-15') --grandchild's order

;with master as (--create recursive (hierarchical) CTE
--anchor query: items w/out parents
select itemid, itemid ParentID --fix value
from @master where ParentID = itemId --parent to itsellf
union all
--recursive query down the tree
select m.itemid, m1.ParentID
from @master m
inner join master m1 on m.ParentID=m1.itemID
)--end CTE
select m.ParentID, max( lo.lastorderdate) lastorderdate
from master m
inner join @LastOrdr lo on m.itemID=lo.ItemID --join by childId
where lo.lastorderdate< '2015-05-29' -- use ISO date
group by m.ParentID --group by parent
```

Comment: Alex, Thanks for the response. in master, for the parent record, I have parentID=2 as well as itemID=2. parent isn't null. what changes would you make to accommodate that in your query?

Comment: I like the fact that it's returning just the parent records for families that meet the criteria. if the data is correct, I can use the parentid to select all the child in each family. Also, I need to provide a where clause, so I added "...from master m where lastorderdate< '05-29-2015'
group by m.Parent_ID" does that look right to you?

Comment: It's up to you provided you add `where` after all `join` and before `group by`. The query takes into account grandchildren also. Do you find the answer acceptable?

Comment: That is part of the question or my main point. To be able to select families that meet the date criteria. I provide a date and want to make sure that max(lastorderdate) is less than the supplied date.

Comment: Hi Alex, having some issues with this solution. it's picking records that it shouldn't

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36dbfe  I have created sample table with data in it. My requirement is: the max date for each family has to be smaller than the date supplied

Comment: Is it greater? I run the query in the fiddle (`where lo.LastReceivingDate < '05-29-2015'`) and receive `324088654 2015-05-08`. May 8, 2015 goes before May 29, 2015.  Just in case, convert string dates to dates.

Comment: 324088654 -> this parent should not be selected given the data. some children of this parent was received in 2016-05-11. I need to find items Parent or Child of the same family that was last received prior to the date supplied. I only have 1 hierarchy level. so the max date of each family has to less than the date. item 320088557 that's under the same parent (324088654) was ordered in 2016 so that family should be dropped all together and I'm not sure where it's pulling the 2015-05-08 date

Comment: remove `where` in final `select` and add `having max(LastReceivingDate)>...` after `goup by...`

Answer (score 1):

You do not post any table structures so I will just give my general approach.
First, I will group the parents and children by creating an additional column to identify the grouping. I would `UNION` the parents and children, with the additional column `parentId`.

```
itemId | parentId
1      | 1
2      | 1
7      | 1
9      | 1
3      | 3
6      | 3
```

From here, you can `GROUP BY parentId` to get the `MAX(lastorderdate)`. I can be more detail if you post the table structures.

Try the query below:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT a.ParentID, MAX(orderdate) AS 'LatestOrder'
    FROM table1 a
    JOIN Table2 b ON b.ItemID = a.ItemID
    GROUP BY ParentID
) c
JOIN table2 d ON d.OrderDate = c.LatestOrder
JOIN table1 e ON e.ItemId = d.ItemId AND e.ParentId = c.ParentID
```

Comment: Added some table structure. As I mentioned in the original post that I also have a P/C hierarchy built. You can see that I already have a parentID field there. Can you show your method in a pseudo select statement?

Comment: Is `ParentId` NULL when Item is a parent?

Comment: No, for parent row in item table, itemid=2 parentID=2.

Comment: My solution works for direct (one level) parent-child relationship.  If you have multiple levels of parent-child relationship, use recursive CTE that Alex posted.

Comment: I'm getting 2 different result sets from the two solutions proposed. I have one level relationship. Let me try to verify the data.

Comment: Thanks Eric for your solution. This was helpful as well.